# Extracting contents of a table in a HTML file using Visual Studio 2013 C++

Tags: string, visual-c++

I am trying to extract folders and file names from a table in an HTML file where each table row consists of two table cells. The first cell will be the folder name and the second cell will be the file name.

The html table that I am trying to extract the folders and files from will all be one a single line, with only the newline after the ending `</table>` tag.  There can be hundreds, if not thousands, of rows on this line.

The example HTML line that I am trying to parse is:

```
<tr><td>C:\folder1\folder2\</td><td>file.jpg</td></tr><tr><td>c:\folder3\folder4\</td><td>file2.jpg</td></tr><tr><td>c:\folder4\folder5\</td><td>file3.jpg</td></tr></table>
```

I have tried to use regular expressions, but its either capturing too much of the line or only returning a single match and not each match. I am a beginner at Regexp in general, let alone within Visual C++.

I have also been trying to use string.find to extract the strings between each `<td>` and `</td>` and though this works, it looks horribly inefficient the way I am doing it. I also have not figured out the best way to read the line of HTML in as if it has thousands of files, reading the whole line in at once may not work well.

The code I am currently using is below. Anyone have any suggestions for a better way to do this?

```
fpos = szLine.find(L"<td>");
szLine.erase(0, fpos);

fpos = szLine.rfind(L"</tr>");

szLine.erase(fpos, szLine.length());

do {

    loopSize = szLine.find(L"</td>");

    if (loopSize == string::npos)
        break;

    wsFolder = szLine.substr(4, loopSize-4);

    szLine.erase(0, loopSize + 5);

    loopSize = szLine.find(L"<td>");

    if (loopSize == string::npos)
        break;

    loopSize = szLine.find(L"</td>");

    if (loopSize == string::npos)
        break;

    wsFolder += szLine.substr(4, loopSize - 4);
    wcout << L"\r\nFile: " << wsFolder << endl << endl;

    fpos = szLine.find(L"</tr>");

    szLine.erase(0, fpos+9);


} while (loopSize != string::npos);
```

Comment: how did you get the html file? can that table be filled with id? may be this can help you. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/663186/HTML-Parser-Cplusplus-Demo-Project
This one too: http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This HTML is generated by a piece of logging software we use internally.  I have tried to get the HTML cleaned up (one table row per newline), but not getting anywhere. Have to work around it.

Comment: if you are writing the html file and using string functions, place ID number for the table and the rows, so you can easily grep them. are you not allowed to use external libraries?

Comment: Unfortunately, the html file format is out of my control. So have to work around the wonky format.